# How to call a string array into a method

Tags: java, arrays, string, methods

I have defined 3 methods in which there are String[] as parameters. I would like to set these ones from another function, with some strings,  and printing each one.

When I try to call these methods from another function(the start() function), to set the values of String[] parameters Eclipse says:

Type mismatch: cannot convert from String 
     to String[]

```
public class logistics2 {

private static String plane;
private static String truck;
private static String airport[];
private static String loc[];
private static String city[];
private static String pack[];


public static void at_obj_place(String object, String[] place) {

    object = truck;
    object = plane;
    place = loc;
    place = city;
    place = airport;

    return;
}

public static void in_pk_vehicle(String[] Pack, String vehicle) {

    Pack = pack;
    vehicle = truck;
    vehicle = plane;

    return;

}

public static void in_city(String[] place, String[] City ) {

    place = loc;
    City = city;

    return;
}





public static void start() {

    // HERE I RECEIVE THE ERROR MESSAGE
    in_city(airport = "cdg", city = "paris");
    in_city(airport = "lhr", city = "london");
    in_city(loc = "north", city = "paris");
    in_city(loc = "south",city = "paris");

    at_obj_place(plane = "plane", airport = "lhr");
    at_obj_place(truck = "truck", airport =  "cdg");
    at_obj_place(pack1 = "p1", airport = "lhr");
    at_obj_place(pack2 = "p2", airport = "lhr");


    for(int i = 0; i < airport[].length(); ) {

        System.out.println(airport + " " + city);
    }



    return;
```

I would like to print each of the values that I have set with the for condition, based on the count of the values number that I have inserted in the String[]

Comment: because you're not passing your function an array should be `in_city(airport  = new String[] { "cd"}, city = new String[]{"paris"});`

Also your code breaks everything that is mean for OOP. why is everything static and why are you assigning values like `vehicles = truck` You are literally overwriting the passed in value with `plane`.

Comment: This code has many issues. I suggest you study the [Oracle Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html). It's a good start.

Comment: Okay thanks now is working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all the methods you have to passed strings you have to pass **array of strings**. Like this for all arrays:

```
airport[0] = "cdg";
airport[1] = "lhr";
city[0] = "paris";
city[1] = "london";
```

then pass this to methods like:

```
in_city(airport,city);
```

And in for loop you have to mention only array name like airport **not airport[]** and add increment for i.